# Image burring in coverflow

Tags: image, coverflow

I have one cover flow of scrollview (with coverflow of view (with image and title)). When I am trying to rotate cover flow with following code images getting blurred. Can anyone help me?

CGAffineTransform tranform  = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, SHKdegreesToRadians(90));

subImageScrollView.coverFlowView.transform = tranform;